# Error dynamically adding table rows in reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a reactJs page that allows an admin add a user to a platform. Now, instead of submitting the form for each new user, I want the admin to be able to add as many users as possible before submitting the form. By default, one table row containing input fields is displayed and then on click of the add button, a new row is added and the admin can fill the necessary details. However, I can't get my page to show the default row and the add button does not work either and unfortunately, my page throws no error. Here is my code:

```
export default class Admins extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            errors : '',
            success : '',
            rows : [1]
        }
        this.addRow = this.addRow.bind(this);
        this.fetchRows = this.fetchRows.bind(this);
    }
    addRow(){
        var last = this.state.rows[this.state.rows.length-1];
        var current = last + 1;
        this.setState({
            rows : this.state.rows.concat(current)
        });
    }
    fetchRows(){
        this.state.rows.map((row, index) => (
            //console.log(row, index)
            <tr key={row}>
                <td className="text-center">
                    <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" className="btn btn-xs btn-danger"
                            data-original-title=""><i className="fa fa-trash"></i>
                    </button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        ));
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Top/>
                <SideBar/>
                <div className="breadcrumb-holder">
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <ul className="breadcrumb">
                            <li className="breadcrumb-item"><Link to="/">Dashboard</Link></li>
                            <li className="breadcrumb-item active">Admins</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <section className="forms">
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <header>
                            <h3 className="h5 display">Admins</h3>
                        </header>

                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-lg-6">
                                <h5 className="text-danger">{this.state.errors}</h5>
                                <h5 className="text-success">{this.state.success}</h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-lg-6">
                                <div className="card">
                                    <div className="card-header d-flex align-items-center">
                                        <h5></h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="card-body">
                                        <table className="table table-bordered">
                                            <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th  width="5%">Actions</th>
                                                <th>Name</th>
                                                <th>Email</th>
                                                <th>Password</th>
                                            </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                {this.fetchRows()}
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td className="text-center">
                                                        <button type="button" onClick={this.addRow} data-toggle="tooltip" className="btn btn-xs btn-primary"
                                                                data-original-title=""><i className="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning anything from `fetchRows`. Return it or simply put it directly in the `render` method and it will work as expected.

**Example**

```
class Admins extends React.Component {
  state = {
    errors: "",
    success: "",
    rows: [1]
  };

  addRow = () => {
    var last = this.state.rows[this.state.rows.length - 1];
    var current = last + 1;
    this.setState({
      rows: this.state.rows.concat(current)
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="breadcrumb-holder">
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <ul className="breadcrumb">
              <li className="breadcrumb-item active">Admins</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <section className="forms">
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <header>
              <h3 className="h5 display">Admins</h3>
            </header>

            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-lg-6">
                <h5 className="text-danger">{this.state.errors}</h5>
                <h5 className="text-success">{this.state.success}</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-lg-6">
                <div className="card">
                  <div className="card-header d-flex align-items-center">
                    <h5 />
                  </div>
                  <div className="card-body">
                    <table className="table table-bordered">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th width="5%">Actions</th>
                          <th>Name</th>
                          <th>Email</th>
                          <th>Password</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        {this.state.rows.map((row, index) => (
                          //console.log(row, index)
                          <tr key={row}>
                            <td className="text-center">
                              <button
                                type="button"
                                data-toggle="tooltip"
                                className="btn btn-xs btn-danger"
                                data-original-title=""
                              >
                                <i className="fa fa-trash" />
                              </button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                              <input type="text" className="form-control" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                              <input type="text" className="form-control" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                              <input type="text" className="form-control" />
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        ))}
                        <tr>
                          <td className="text-center">
                            <button
                              type="button"
                              onClick={this.addRow}
                              data-toggle="tooltip"
                              className="btn btn-xs btn-primary"
                              data-original-title=""
                            >
                              <i className="fa fa-plus" />
                            </button>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! I totally forgot.

Comment: @radioactive You're welcome! It happens to all of us.